# Search based on regular expression in mgo does not give required result

Tags: go, mgo

Hello I have the following code in my golang:

Please take a look:

```
type User struct {
    Id              int      `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    FirstName       string   `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
    LastName        string   `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
    EmailId         string   `json:"email_id" bson:"email_id"`
    Password        string   `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    PhoneNumber     string   `json:"phone_number" bson:"phone_number"`
    AltPhoneNumber  string   `json:"alt_phone_number" bson:"alt_phone_number"`
    Gender          string   `json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
    Note            string   `json:"note" bson:"note"`
    Address         string   `json:"address" bson:"address"`
    AptNo           string   `json:"apt_no" bson:"apt_no"`
    City            string   `json:"city" bson:"city"`
    Zipcode         string   `json:"zipcode" bson:"zipcode"`
}

query   := bson.M{  "role"   : "customer", 
                    "status" : 1, 
                    "$or": []bson.M{ 
                        bson.M{"first_name":bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword+"*.", "i"} },
                        bson.M{"last_name": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword+"*.", "i"} }, 
                        bson.M{"email_id": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                        bson.M{"phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                        bson.M{"alt_phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                }}

err = c.Find(query).All(&result)
```

I have a record in database with first name "swati" and last name "sharma".
When I search "swati" then it works properly, similarly when I search "sharma"
it works properly.

Issue is when I search "swati sharma" then it does not return any result. 
Can anybody tell how I can achieve this output?

Comment: try something like
 `&bson.RegEx{Pattern: fmt.Sprintf(".*%s*.", keyword), Options: "i"}`

also test your regex using https://regex101.com/

Notice my regex is a pointer. `&`. I use `fmt.Sprintf` because concatenations are harder to read and easier to mess up (my opinion)

You may also want to break up your logic and test.. for instance make a query just using your original logic
`bson.M{"first_name":bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword+"*.", "i"} }` don't complicate it with the or, status, or role.  Isolate and test your regex first

Comment: it also seems like your regex should work, assuming your keyword is what you expect it to be and doesn't have extra spaces, characters, etc
https://regex101.com/r/B9F3Wp/1

So there is something else going on

Comment: @reticentroot I have checked there is no extra space with my keyword. I think the regex is correct, the only difference is I compared the string full name against first_name and last_name from db

Comment: the full name isn't going to match on anything see for the updated regex regex101.com/r/B9F3Wp/4

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes in my code and it works.

```
    name := strings.Replace(keyword, " ", "|", -1)
        conditions := bson.M{ "role" : config.ProviderRole, 
                                "status" : status, 
                                "$or": []bson.M{ 
                                    bson.M{"first_name":bson.RegEx{"(?i).*"+name+".*", "i"} },
                                    bson.M{"last_name": bson.RegEx{ "(?i).*"+name+".*", "i"} }, 
                                    bson.M{"email_id": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                                    bson.M{"phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                                    bson.M{"alt_phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*"+keyword, "i"} }, 
                                }}
    err = c.Find(query).All(&result)
```